# Translating Kotlin to Java: mapTo

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, priority-queue

I am a beginner in programming and have to translate                                                                                                                                                        kotlin code to java for a project. 
If I understand it correctly, the following method maps indices from the float-array "results" to the newly created PriorityQueue.

```
private fun getResults():PriorityQueue<Result>{
val outputQueue = createOutputQueue()
**results.indices.mapTo(outputQueue) { Result(labels[it], results[it]) }** ;this is the main problem 
return outputQueue
}
```

This is  what I've got so far:

```
public final PriorityQueue<Result> getResults(){
PriorityQueue outputQueue = new PriorityQueue(createOutputQueue());
for (int i =0; i<results.length+1;i++){
...
}
return outputQueue;
```

The only solution I could think of is iterating over the array with a for loop. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what's wrong with the solution you could think of?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to write it because I'm not fully understanding the third line of the kotlin code.

Comment: you wrote "the only solution I could think of is iterating over the array with a for loop"... and that is what you have to do... ;-) try it and show what problems you face, if any... if you want to understand, what the code does, you may want to lookup the appropriate Kotlin reference, e.g. for [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) and [`mapTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html#mapto)...

Comment: "have to translate kotlin code to java for a project".  I'm so very sorry for your loss. :)

Comment: To comment on understanding. In Kotlin `{ }` means lambda expression. For the case of `mapTo` function, the lambda has one parameter. It is implicitly called `it`. You may have a longer syntax `{ your_variable_name -> compute(your_variable_name) }`

Every function allows to have its last lambda parameter to be coded outside of `()`, thus you may have `mapTo(target, { ... })` and it is equivalent to `mapTo(target) { ... }`. The second reads a bit nicer and used widely.

Comment: The first question that came up now is how to create a Map using labels (type List) and results (float[]). I tried " Map<labels,results> map = new HashMap<>() " which didn't work so I used " Map<List,float[]> map = new HashMap<>() " which does work but I don't know how to incorporate the two variables.